# how to create breadcrumbs in website using php

Tags: php, html, css

How can i create breadcrumbs in my website. For example if i go to signin page from my home page then i want to show a breadcrumb like home->signin
i have tried like this is the link of my signin page on my home page

```
<a href="signin.php?id=1">signin</a>
```

and on signin page i have said that

```
if(isset($_GET['id']==1))
{
echo '<a>Home</a> -> <a>signin</a> ';
}
```

i guess this will work fine when i will navigate from home page to signin page but what if i move from some other page to signin page how could i dynamically change that home->signin part to home->products->signin etc

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and there's many, many possible answers. There's server side libraries, client side libraries, and you could roll your own. Can you refine your requirements and constraints?

Comment: Just google your title and you'll find so many answers. Read this: http://www.baskettcase.com/classes/breadcrumb/ .

Comment: i am new to web development i am making a eCommerce website. and i want to show on different page navigation's the path where user is like whenever a user move from one page to the next he could see breadcrumbs like home->product-productdetail etc

Comment: i havent tried anything yet actually i am not getting the idea how to do it i have stated in my question what i have tried.
i just need direction how to do it i am not asking to do it for me should i use libraries or what?